# Store password for relogin later in C++ app

Tags: c++, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm writing C++ desktop application that allows users to sign in on some web service. By technical requirements, user can check 'remember me' checkbox and after he close app and run it again, app should re-sign in with email and password user input first time.

I know that it is not safe and strongly not recommended to store passwords on disk but i have no idea how to remember user's password in safe way. Is there any best practices or advices for such case?

Note: my application is for Windows/Ubuntu/MacOS so it will be cool to know about OS-independent ways. My app is C++11/Qt5.4 based.

Comment: You can store a decently encrypted password??

Comment: Sure i can. I'm just asking about best practices.

Comment: _"I'm just asking about best practices."_ Which turns out to be _to broad_ and likely being closed as off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're supposed to implement this kind of design is to issue the user a SessionID that is stored locally, and which is used to authenticate and access their specific interface. Then, if they wish to log in again at a later time, simply use the stored SessionID, and if they wish to log in as someone else, clear the SessionID and then log them in like normal, issuing a new SessionID. That way you aren't storing sensitive information on their computer.

Comment: Unfortunately web service invalidates session IDs in some cases like long-time user inactivity.

Comment: Right, but you're the one writing the application. You get to choose how/when that functionality should be implemented.